# How to use the database driver only for session blocking?

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I am currently using the `file` cache driver as the default cache driver.
But now I need to be able to use Session Blocking: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/session#session-blocking

I want to prevent multiple HTTP requests at the same time on some `/api-endpoint`.

How can I use the `database` driver only for this purpose? The problem is - how can I specify for the API route that I want to use the `database` driver for the blocking:

```
Route::post('/api-endpoint', function () {
    // ...
})->block($lockSeconds = 10, $waitSeconds = 10)
```

I assume the `block` method will try to use the default driver which is the `file`? But how can I specify that it should be the `database` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Create a session table `php artisan session:table`

Run migration `php artisan migrate`

Change session driver in your `.env`

```
SESSION_DRIVER=database
```

Once you have set up Laravel to use the database driver for session storage, it will automatically take care of session blocking.

**Note:** Session blocking is only work when you use the `database` or `cache` driver to store your session. If you're using the default file driver, you cannot use session blocking.

Here is the custom session block solution:
[How to Block Session in Laravel](https://blog.bajarangisoft.com/blog/how-can-i-block-sessions-in-laravel-framework-with-example)